# Celery Beat schedules multiple tasks but only runs the first one

Tags: python, celery

I'm facing an issue with Celery where I have multiple tasks scheduled in Celery Beat, but only the one task(notify_after_sobes) is being executed. In the Celery Beat logs, I can see that all the tasks are recognized and scheduled:

```
[2023-12-07 14:56:00,042] celery.beat INFO Scheduler: Sending due task send_sobes_link (celery_settings.tasks.notify_send_sobes_link)
[2023-12-07 14:56:00,042] celery.beat INFO Scheduler: Sending due task after_sobes (celery_settings.tasks.notify_after_sobes)
```

Here's an example of my Celery configuration:

```py
app = Celery('tasks')
app.config_from_object(celeryconfig)
app.conf.timezone = 'Europe/Kiev'
app.conf.enable_utc = False

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'notify_tomorrow_sobes_task': {
        'task': 'celery_settings.tasks.notify_tomorrow_sobes',
        'schedule': crontab(minute="00", hour="18"),
    },
    'send_sobes_link': {
        'task': 'celery_settings.tasks.notify_send_sobes_link',
        'schedule': crontab(minute="5"),
    },
    'after_sobes': {
        'task': 'celery_settings.tasks.notify_after_sobes',
        'schedule': crontab(minute="5"),
    },
}
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task
def notify_tomorrow_sobes():
    asyncio.run(send_notify_tomorrow_sobes())

@app.task
def notify_send_sobes_link():
    asyncio.run(send_sobes_link())

@app.task
def notify_after_sobes():
    asyncio.run(after_sobes())
```

Thank you!

Second task(notify_send_sobes_link) failed with error: NotRegistered('celery_settings.tasks.notify_send_sobes_link')

[image: second task error img]

Comment: Are the tasks defined in module celery_settings-->tasks.py--> notify_tomorrow_sobes or in configs itself ? can you try adding correct package in autodiscover ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the tasks are being recognized and scheduled by Celery Beat, but only the `notify_after_sobes` task is being executed. To troubleshoot this issue:

1. Check if the other tasks (`send_sobes_link` in this case) have any issues with their code or dependencies. Look into the task definition and its implementation.
2. Ensure that the tasks have the correct configurations in Celery, including the correct queue, concurrency settings, and any other relevant settings.
3. Review the logs for the tasks that are not being executed to see if there are any error messages or warnings that might provide insights into the problem.
4. Verify if there are any conflicts or overlaps in the scheduling of these tasks. Check if the tasks have different schedules that might be causing them to collide.
5. Double-check the Celery Beat schedule settings to ensure there are no misconfigurations or errors in specifying the schedule for each task.

If the issue persists, providing more details about the task definitions, Celery configurations, and any error messages would be helpful for further assistance.